# Extend a border in CSS without pushing other elements down

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

http://adamginther.com/timeline.php

For portfolio purposes I am trying to create a timeline of my history in the industry.

The blue line for Capilano University pushes the rest of the elements down on hover, is there any way to make it extend from the bottom to the top? I have tried position: absolute; but that didn't do any thing.

HTML

```
<div id="timeline-wrapper">
        <div id="timeline">
            <span class="circle"></span>
                <span class="timeline-element" id="capu">
                    <h1>Capilano University</h1>
                    <p>September 2012 - April 2014</p>
                </span>

                <span class="timeline-element bottom" id="spud">
                    <p class="work-description">I worked underneath the Senior VP of Customer Experience, along with the Lead Designer and the Lead Storyteller to help re-build the SPUD brand via banners, landing pages, and newsletters. I also spent three months building a new marketing website from the ground up</p>
                    <h1>SPUD</h1>
                    <p>May 2013 - March 2014</p>
                </span>

                <span class="timeline-element bottom" id="pandg">
                    <p class="work-description">
                    Working under technical lead Chris Ng, the technologies I primarily used were HTML, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery, Git, and WordPress. Over the span of six weeks I built a WordPress plug-in for Leaflet, imported a blog for Vitala Foods, and created a fake kale store, and many other various bug fixes and small projects.</p>
                    <h1>Pound & Grain</h1>
                    <p>March 2014 - April 2014</p>
                </span>

                <span class="timeline-element bottom" id="relentless">
                    <p class="work-description">Relentless Technology is a small boutique agency in North Vancouver with clients such as Blast Radius, Wunderman, and Levi's. My primary role was to perform maintainence and bug fixes in WordPress, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for their 300+ clients.</p>
                    <h1>Relentless Technology</h1>
                    <p>April 2014 - July 2014</p>
                </span>


            <span class="circle right"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#timeline {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #25b67b;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.2s;

}
.bordernone {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
    transition: 1s;
}
#timeline-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 175px 0;
}
#timeline .circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 7px solid #25b67b;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#timeline .circle.right {
    right: 0;
}
#timeline .circle:hover {
    background: #25b67b;
}
#timeline .timeline-element {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
#timeline .timeline-element.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
}
#timeline .work-description {
    text-align: left !important;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.5s !important;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 150px;
}
#timeline #capu {
    border-bottom: #015289 5px solid;
    background: url(../img/arrow-capu.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: 35px;
    width: 66%;
    margin-left: 39px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
#timeline #capu:hover {
    border-bottom: #015289 15px solid;
}
#timeline #spud {
    border-top: #efad36 5px solid;
    background: url(../img/arrow-spud.png) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 35px;
    width: 28%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13%;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
#timeline #spud:hover {
    border-top: #efad36 10px solid;
}
#timeline #spud .work-description {
    background: #efad36;
}
#timeline #pandg {
    border-top: #ef4035 5px solid;
    background: url(../img/arrow-pandg.png) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 35px;
    width: 28%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 41%;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
#timeline #pandg .work-description {
    background: #ef4035;
}
#timeline #pandg:hover {
    border-top: #ef4035 10px solid;
}
#timeline #relentless {
    border-top: #f89728 5px solid;
    background: url(../img/arrow-relentless.png) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 35px;
    width: 28%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 69%;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
#timeline #relentless:hover {
    border-top: #f89728 10px solid;
}
#timeline #relentless .work-description {
    background: #f89728;
}
#timeline .timeline-element h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#timeline .timeline-element p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html').click(function() {
        $('.work-description').hide();
    });
    $('#spud').click(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#spud .work-description').show();
    });
    $('#pandg').click(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#pandg .work-description').show();
    });
    $('#relentless').click(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#relentless .work-description').show();
    });
    $('#capu').click(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#capu .work-description').show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the box model to `border-box` that will keep the overall height the same regardles of what you do to the border, padding etc:

```
.borderBox {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

That will effectively "let these things change on the inside".

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3duL/3/

There's a nice rundown here:

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: I have tried using this on #timeline, and nearly every element within it but it seems to make no difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ha ha - sure; I've updated the fiddle to look more like your thing: http://jsfiddle.net/X3duL/3/